# Better Workspace Switch Indication Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, workspaces

Is there a way to install a better indicator that I have changed workspaces in Linux Mint? For instance currently I get the text in the center of the screen saying `Workspace 1`, `Workspace 2`, etc. Is there a way to get something that looks like this or workspace switchers I am more used to:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Now in 2023 I've found it:
https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/222 ("Workspace Name").

To edit names I've understood one need to edit dconf database. However, for diplayed on the panel name purposes I've edited javascript:

```
let name = 'ws-'+ (activeWorkspace.index()+1); //Main.getWorkspaceName(activeWorkspace.index());
```